# Parse Swift: Check if update was successfully committed

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am performing an update operation and would like to know how can I know if the saveInBackground was successful or not. The code I am using is below. If successful I will show alert view and if not then I will display error.

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId!) {
    (userInstance: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else if let userInstance = userInstance {
        userInstance["number1"] = number1
        userInstance["number2"] = number2
        userInstance.saveInBackground()
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cancelChangesSegue", sender: nil)

        var alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Number Updated!"
        alert.message = "You've successfully updatd your number"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Great!")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userInstance.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            // The object has been saved.
            // Do stuff here
            var alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Number Updated!"
            alert.message = "You've successfully updatd your number"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Great!")
            alert.show()
        } else {
           // There was a problem, check error.description
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `saveInBackground`, then make use of the method `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:`. This has a boolean parameter called `succeeded` which you can use to trigger the alert.

You can read more about the method on [the official Parse API docs here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveInBackgroundWithBlock:)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should already be doing this. The `Parse` function returns an `NSError` or a `PFObject`. If the error is returned, meaning `error != nil`, then you already know that the save wasn't successful for some reason. In your `else` clause you already display the alert upon the successful return of saving your object, so I'm not sure why you think this doesn't work as the question described unless I misunderstood you.